# want same satellite view as google map application

Tags: android, dictionary

[image: Iam getting the display as following from my code]I want a satellite view as in a Google Map app.  I am using Satellite View for my current location and it is getting the image, but it is not as same as google map!

I just want a same view as it is in picture or as we get from Google map app as in satellite view

[image: Example image from Google Maps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following links-

1.[Android Working with Google Maps](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/)

2.[Android working with Google Maps V2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

3.[Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: I don't have problem in displaying map. I am facing a problem that for same location satellite view in google map is different and in my app view is different

Comment: Answers with only links are not so good. One should add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there and also because a link may not direct to the same page in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
you just need to set map type as satelite to get satelite view.

     private GoogleMap mMap;

//for normal view of map:
     mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


//for satelite view of map:
    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```